# Populate Dropdown List on page (not in dialog) from JSON data

Tags: json, servlets, aem

I'm new to CQ. What I'd like to do is be able to populate one of the out-of-the-box Dropdown List components on a page from data retrieved in a service or servlet.

I've seen solutions for populating a field on the edit dialog from a servlet, but not on the page itself. I know I can manually add each individual row to the dropdown in the edit panel of the dropdown. I also have seen the Items Load Path that I can provide a path to a node's property that is of type String[] where each element of the property is formatted key=value. Both of these solutions are very manual and provide no flexibility for a list that needs to be somewhat dynamic.

I know I can also define a servlet path and load the dropdown manually via an ajax call...but this data is static enough that for efficiency's sake it could/should be retrieved at the time the page is built instead of another round-trip to the server. It would seem to me that there should be a way to bind a dropdown to some JSON data that gets built dynamically in a servlet or service and populated into the dropdown as the page is being built.  Perhaps pointing the Items Load Path to a node whose resource type is somehow bound to the servlet?

I'm just so new to CQ that I'm having trouble figuring out how to tie these things together, but it seems like it would be a fairly common need to populate a dropdown with data that I don't have to manually hardcode into the page or a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that I had phrased my question well enough back when I wrote it. I've learned a bit since then and so I think what I was trying to say was I wanted to have a way to generate "synthetic" nodes that aren't truly backed in the JCR, but rather dynamically built. What I ultimately ended up figuring out how to do was write a [ResourceProvider](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/portlet/ResourceProvider.html).  My specific use case for this was to provide an easy way for authors to populate dropdown components via data that originates from two places:

- packaged property files
- calls to an external REST resource

My inspiration for my solution came largely from this article: http://www.lucamasini.net/Home/sling-and-cq5/accessing-relational-data-as-sling-restful-urls

Here is a large majority of the class that I wrote. I left out the logic to read from the property files and REST resources as that wasn't the point of the question.

```
@Component(
    name = "DropdownResourceProvider",
    label = "DropdownResourceProvider",
    description = "Dropdown Resource Provider")
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "service.description", value = "Dropdown Resource Provider"),
    @Property(name = ResourceProvider.ROOTS, value = "/content/<app-name>/dropdown")
})
public class DropdownResourceProvider implements ResourceProvider {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropdownResourceProvider.class);

    private String providerRoot;
    private String providerRootPrefix;

    protected void activate(BundleContext bundleContext, Map<?, ?> props) {
        providerRoot = props.get(ROOTS).toString();
        providerRootPrefix = providerRoot.concat("/");
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(ResourceResolver resourceResolver,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String path) {
        return getResource(resourceResolver, path);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, final String path) {
        if (providerRoot.equals(path) || providerRootPrefix.equals(path)) {
            log.info("path " + path + " matches this provider root folder: "
                    + providerRoot);
            return new SyntheticResource(resourceResolver, path, "sling:Folder");
        } else {
            String relativePath = path.substring(providerRootPrefix.length());

            final String[] pathSegments = relativePath.split("/");

            if (pathSegments.length > 0) {
                String[] dropdownOptions; // will be a string array formatted like this: ["key=value","key=value"]

                if (REST_SEGMENT_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(pathSegments[0])) {
                    ...invoke rest service based on information extracted from path segment values and build synthetic resources based on results...
                    dropdownOptions = ...set string array to results of rest invocation, formatted as needed...
                } else if (PROPERTIES_SEGMENT_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(pathSegments[0])) {
                    ...read property file based on information extracted from path segment values and build synthetic resources based on results...
                    dropdownOptions = ...set string array to results of parsing property file, formatted as needed...
                }

                String propsPath = providerRootPrefix + StringUtils.join(Arrays.copyOfRange(pathSegments, 0, pathSegments.length - 1), "/");

                return new SyntheticResource(resourceResolver, propsPath, "sling:Folder/" + pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 1]) {
                    public <T> T adaptTo(Class<T> type) { 
                        return (T) dropdownOptions; 
                     } 
                };
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void deactivate() {
        this.providerRoot = null;
        this.providerRootPrefix = null;
    }
}
```

This allows me to then go into the edit component dialog of the out-of-the-box Dropdown component and set the Items Load Path to the path that my resource provider will answer to. You can see in the below example, this would point to a property file whose contents is a listing of countries that a user should be allowed to select from. Storing these in the repository wasn't necessary, and this provides an easy, dynamic way for an author to point to known resources (properties, REST services, whatever you need) and easily fill dropdowns without having to have custom components built or without having to enter hundreds of items in the repository.

[image]

Comment: Nice example. Can you share the full class/code for the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP template for the component just needs to iterate over a map of keys & values inside the dropdown.  JSON is probably not the most efficient method of passing the map to the JSP - better to have a service just return a map directly instead of serializing to JSON then deserializing it in your component.

An example of an HTML select component that provides its own (static) map of states (could provide an alternate source of the map):

```
<%
final Map<String, String> stateMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
  put("Alabama","AL");
  put("Alaska","AK");
  put("Arizona","AZ");
  ...
}};
List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
stateList.addAll(stateMap.keySet());
Collections.sort(stateList);

final String selectedState = (String) request.getAttribute("state-selected");
%><c:set var="name" value="<%= resource.getName() %>" />
<c:set var="selectedState" value="<%= selectedState %>" />
<c:set var="stateMap" value="<%= stateMap %>" />
<label for="${name}">${label}</label>
<select id="${name}" name="${name}">
    <option value=""><%= properties.get("select", "Select Your State") %></option>
    <c:forEach var="state" items="<%= stateList %>">
        <option value="${stateMap[state]}" ${ selectedState==stateMap[state] ? " selected" : ""}>${state}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Again, the "map" doesn't have to be a constant - it can be built from parsing JSON response, or reading sets of properties for the resource, or ....  to be truly dynamic the dialog might prompt for the url for the JSON, but much better to just have an OSGi service that provides the data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had considered using this approach, but what I was looking for was something more generic. In other words, I wanted to be able to use an out-of-the-box component and supply it with a path (optionsLoadPath) and have it just automatically populate with the desired data. This will be especially useful for page authors who want to drag components on the page, but aren't writing their own custom components.  I did actually find the solution I was looking for. See my answer below.